# SQL Server: how to insert a record into related table during an update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say we have two tables, **`Incidents`** and **`IncidentTracking`**:

```
Incidents (Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
            CreatedOn Datetime,
            State VARCHAR(50))

IncidentTracking (Id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
                  IncidentId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TO Incidents.Id,
                  TrackingDate Datetime,
                  NewState VARCHAR(50))
```

How do I insert a new record into `IncidentTracking` while updating some incidents?

For example, I want to change the `State` for all incidents that are more than 90 days old to "Outdated", and insert a tracking info record where `IncidentId` is the updated incident (`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` maybe?), `TrackingDate` is `GETDATE()` and `NewState` is also "Outdated".

Can it be done all in one statement or should I write a cursor?

Comment: Surely outdated is derived from the date, not a state in itself.  You can do what you ask in one statement though I'm on a tablet so can't write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

As `IncidentTracking` has a foreign key, it is not possible to OUTPUT directly to it. You'll get an error message if you try:

> The target table 'dbo.IncidentTracking' of the OUTPUT INTO clause
>   cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship.
>   Found reference constraint 'FK_IncidentTracking_Incidents'.

So, we can use a temporary table or table variable.
Like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @T TABLE (IncidentId int, TrackingDate datetime, NewState varchar(50));

UPDATE [dbo].[Incidents]
SET [State] = 'Outdated'
OUTPUT 
    inserted.Id AS [IncidentId], 
    GETDATE() AS [TrackingDate], 
    inserted.[State] AS [NewState]
INTO @T ([IncidentId], [TrackingDate], [NewState])
WHERE [CreatedOn] < DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())
;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[IncidentTracking] ([IncidentId], [TrackingDate], [NewState])
SELECT [IncidentId], [TrackingDate], [NewState]
FROM @T;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thank you, @VladimirBaranov, I tried with OUTPUT INTO and got that error, indeed. The temp table is a good workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Write a stored procedure to perform your task. You can put that kind of logic in a stored procedure easily enough.

If you will allow access to the table(s) outside of the procedure and still want the same behavior, a trigger is likely what you want (not a fan of them myself). Make sure, when writing your trigger, you remember that it will run against a ***recordset*** not a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a trigger on the `state` field that inserts into `IncidentTracking`, then you just need the one update. Or the other way around (adding to `IncidentTracking` updates `State`)

But why even have the `State` in the `Incidents` table? Just have an `IncidentState` table where you add every state change, and the latest added one is the current state for the incident.

You'd also probably want to make the `State` field a `StateId` column instead of a text code. Connected to a `State` table containing all the states.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, @Jan. This is a simplified scenario. In the actual one, State is an integer, and it is repeated in the Incidents table due to the Entity Framework performance issues with too many joins